# One-line `if` return statement with two actions

Tags: ruby, coding-style

I'm searching for an elegant way to bring the following `if` statement into one line:

```
if var1.nil?
  log("some message")
  return
end
```

I love the right hand `if` statement where you can say

```
return if var1.nil?
```

In this case, I need two actions, but the following doesn't work:

```
log("some message") and return if var1.nil?
```

Is there a way to perform two actions (log message and return) with an `if` at the right side in one line?

Comment: The reason it's not working is because your `log` method returns `nil` or `false`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. When you have a method like `return`, `break`, etc., you can do (assuming that you are not interested in the return value):

   ```
   return log("some message") if var1.nil?
   ```
2. A naive general way is:

   ```
   (log("some message"); return) if var1.nil?
   ```
3. But if you don't like the parentheses and semicolon, then, do this: If `and` does not work, then that means the return value of the first expression is falsy, which means `or` should work.

   ```
   log("some message") or return if var1.nil?
   ```

   In general, one or the other between `and` and `or` would work, depending on the evaluated value of the first expression.

Comment: Isn't this an ugly hack? Also what if the return value of the `log` method depends on what is being logged (like `Kernel.p`)?

Comment: ...,whereas (continuing @ndn's second sentence) the OP's `if` statement returns `nil`.

Comment: Indeed, 3. is an ugly hack. That is not the way to go. 2. is the cleanest. 1. is the next.

Answer (score 6):

Well, to not depend on boolean evaluations you can always do something like this:

```
(log('some message'); return) if var.nil?
```

But I personally find it much less readable than the multiline version

```
if var1.nil?
  log('some message')
  return
end
```

One problem with the modifier-if syntax is that you may not even notice it when the line is too long. Observe:

```
(log('Something really bad happened while you were doing that thing with our app and we are terribly sorry about that. We will tell our engineers to fix this. Have a good day'); return) if var.nil?
```

Comment: The "one problem" could be fixed by pushing that noise into a separate method (`def log_blah_blah; log('...'); return; end`) and then saying `return log_blah_blah if(var.nil?)`. I do that sort of thing quite a bit when I have a stack of `return false_and_set_msg if(condition)` things.

Comment: @muistooshort: yeah, that example is a bit contrived, but you get the idea. Sometimes the meat of that line is used only once, and it may not be worth it to extract the method. Also putting the condition front and center highlights the special case here. I personally use modifier-ifs for `return unless user` kind of lines mostly.

Comment: All examples are a bit contrived :) There's all kinds of *sometimes* and *maybes* around this sort of thing. I do a fair bit of `return true if(...)\nreturn false if(...)...` sorts of things in access control methods, sort of a "lazy evaluated look up table" construct that is compact and reads nicely. Opinions etc.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on your version of Ruby, there is another way to achieve this that is (in my opinion) a little more readable. The `yield_self` method that was introduced in Ruby 2.5 has an alias called `then` as of Ruby 2.6. It is available on all descendents of `Object` (just about everything, including `nil`).

```rb
log("some message").then { return } if var1.nil?
```

Since the `return` keyword will actually exit the current method or lambda context, you can place the return inside the block provided to `then`. Alternatively, you can just return the result of `then` since it returns the resolved block value.

```rb
return log("some message").then { nil } if var1.nil?
```

The latter example would also be good for an early exit when the context is another block.

```rb
some_vars.map do |var1|
  next log("some message").then { nil } if var1.nil?

  # do something with var1
end
```

Personally, I think the first example reads a bit better, but it's nice to have a little flexibility when you need it.